# Extracting an int out of void*

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a method that returns `void*` and it is basically some block of data from allocated shared memory on linux.

The first 4 bytes in that data are an `int` and I haven't managed to extract that int.

These are the methods what I have tried:

```
int getNum(void* data) 
{
    return *(int*)data; // 1
    return *(int*)(data & 0xFFFFFFFF); // 2
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the content of data? And what is what you get?

Comment: The content is an int, and then a flag that is one byte... I get a segmentation fault

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @GioraGuttsait `(data & 0xFFFFFFFF)` masks the pointer not the data itself.

Comment: Don't you need to use `shmget()` or something? I don't think you can just access random memory?

Comment: The shared memory is allocated long before that method

Comment: Do you know the endianess ?

Comment: What about writing it explicitely? `int *p_data = (int*)data; return p_data[0];`. If this does not work make sure you initialized the memory and it didn't get reallocated by something else (e.g. exiting from the scope where it was created)

Comment: But is it allocated in a way that this process can directly read it from its own virtual address space?

Comment: _"I have a method"_ - where from?  A well-known library?  Another part of your code?  There must be source and/or documentation available to help us help you...

Comment: frarugi, I'll try that when I get on my working pc. Thanks for the answers tho guys

Comment: Toby, I'm using an internal library that wraps shared memory for a nosql database. Does it matter how I get the void*?

Comment: @GioraGuttsait If you want to guarantee that only 4 bytes of `data` are used, you should use `int32_t` for the casts.

Comment: I was dumb enough not to try `*data`... You don't have to lynch me for not knowing how to do that kind of thing guys

Comment: What platform are you using?  Could you be having problems with non-aligned access?  If so, the simplest solution is `int result; memcpy(&result, data, sizeof(int));`

Comment: ?? `*data` should not be legal.  (Because it's a void).

Comment: No martin, see the comment before yours. I'm just dumb

Comment: @MartinBonner Aligned access is a good point. But using `int32_t` would be better though.

Comment: @πάντα: "*`(data & 0xFFFFFFFF)` masks the pointer not the data itself*"` -- No, it doesn't. It doesn't do *anything*, since the `&` operator cannot be applied to `void*`.

Comment: @KeithThompson [You're right actually](http://ideone.com/kGNF4e).

Comment: Please update your question to indicate exactly *how* both your methods failed. The second should not compile; if your code did compile, please update the question to show your actual exact code.

Comment: _"Does it matter how I get the `void*`?_" The reason it matters is that you/we should consult the documentation and/or source of the library to see how you're intended to use the result.  Without that, it's all guesswork, really.

Answer (score 2):

```
int getNum(void* data) 
{
    return *(int32_t*)data; // 1
          // ^^^^^^^
}
```

Should work.

Also if you need to worry about unaligned addresses achieved from the `void*`, you may use [@Martin Bonner's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159534/extracting-an-int-out-of-void/35159909?noredirect=1#comment58038118_35159534):

```
int getNum(void* data) 
{
    int32_t result;
    memcpy(&result, data, sizeof(int32_t));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out as soon as I'll get my hands on the workstation

Comment: How is that different from what is currently being used? Modulo the fixed-width integral type, that is.

Comment: @Lightness Is `int` being guaranteed to be 32 bits fixed? I liked Martin Bonner's point about aligned access though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No so if your point is to use `int32_t` rather than `int`, that's probably a good suggestion. But switching `*` to `[0]` detracts from the point IMO i.e. it's not clear which change you're suggesting :)

Comment: @Lightness Changed the answer a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: The problem statement says the pointer points to an `int`. Why are you changing it to `int32_t`? Extracting an `int32_t` might be a better problem to solve, but if you're going to change the requirements you should say so.

Comment: @KeithThompson _"The first 4 bytes in ..."_ The requirements was **4 bytes** from the source. If that's converted to a plain `int` after extraction, does that matter for the result?

Comment: In principle, yes, it could matter. Type `int` might have padding bits. More realistically, the OP already said that `return *(int*)data;` didn't work; replacing `int` by `int32_t` isn't likely to change that.

Comment: The question says that the required data is 4 bytes, and that it's of type `int`. On a system where `int` is not 4 bytes, *one* of those will become invalid -- but we don't know which. You're assuming that the 4-byte size is invariant, but it could just as easily be the type that doesn't change. The OP needs to clarify this (among other things).

Answer (score 1):

```
int getNum(void* data) 
{
    return *(int*)data; // 1
    return *(int*)(data & 0xFFFFFFFF); // 2
}
```

The second method won't even compile; `data` is a pointer, and you cannot apply the `&` bitwise and operator to a pointer value. (I don't know why you'd even want to mask a pointer value like that. If it were legal, the mask would do nothing on a 32-bit system, and would probably destroy the pointer value on a 64-bit system.)

As for the first, it should work -- *if* `data` is a valid pointer pointing to a properly aligned `int` object.

If that's failing at run time with a segmentation fault, it probably means either that `data` is null or otherwise not a valid pointer (in that case you *can't* do what you're trying to do), or it points to a misaligned address (which won't cause a seg fault if you're on an x86 or x86_64 system; are you?).

To find out what the pointer looks like, try adding this:

```
printf("data = %p\n", data);
```

to your `getNum` function -- or examine the value of `data` in a debugger.

If alignment is the problem, then you can do this:

```
int result;
memcpy(&result, data, sizeof result);
return result;
```

But in that case storing an `int` value as a misaligned address is an odd thing to do in the first place. It's not necessarily wrong, just a very odd thing to do.

How is the memory that `data` points to allocated?

Comment: The masking was probably meant to be applied to the resulting value, I'd suspect a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the int is 4 bytes long, and you're operating on Linux, your method will work.  If you want a portable method to move ints in pointers, try the open source [ptrint](http://ccodearchive.net/info/ptrint.html) module from CCAN.  It converts a pointer to int by adding NULL to the int.  It converts in the other direction by subtracting NULL, returning a ptrdiff_t.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int getNum(void* data)
{
        return *(int *) data;
}

char buf[16];
int main(void)
{
        assert(sizeof(int) == 4);

        *(int *)buf = 9;

        printf("%c%c%c%c\n", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]);

        printf("%d\n", getNum((void *) buf));

        return 0;
}

// $ ./foo | cat -tv
// ^I^@^@^@
// 9
```

Comment: Adding `NULL` to an `int` would convert an `int` to a pointer. But it's hardly portable; pointer arithmetic on a null pointer has undefined behavior. If you really need to convert pointers to integers or vice versa, use a cast. BTW, your `getNum` function is the same as the first method shown in the question, which the OP already said didn't work.

Comment: Yes, but the ptrint module casts the NULL, like so: return (ptrint_t *)((char *)NULL + i);  I know the getNum is identical to the OP - I'm trying to demonstrate that it **does** work, and therefore the OP might have a problem elsewhere, such as where the value is initially written to the memory.